# How to use Zipfile to extract all files in one directory

Tags: c#, zip

ith my simple C# form app I want to click a button(FolderBrowserDialog) and navigate to a folder on my computer.

This folder will contain dozens of zip files.  I will then select this folder.

In the folder that I had selected, the program should then create one subfolder for each zip file, name the subfolders with the name of their respective zip files, and decompress the content of the zip files in their respective subfolders.

In my code (below) I have no problems in selecting the parent folder and assigning the path to a string variable sbDir.

The problem I am having is passing sbDir to private void Decompress which should then create the subfolders and decompress the zip files.

How can I resolve this issue?

Below is the code I am using.

```
namespace HealthCheckScanner
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string sbDir = null;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Get the zip files parent directory
        private void sbFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                sbDir = Convert.ToString(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            }
        }

        //Uncompress all zip files in their own directory using zip file name in the parent directory
        private void Decompress(DirectoryInfo sbDir)
        {

            foreach (FileInfo file in sbDir.GetFiles())
            {
                string fileName = (Regex.Replace(sbDir + file.Name, ".Zip", ""));
                string filePath = Convert.ToString(sbDir);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, filePath);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to find a solution using the following code

```
//Get the zip files parent directory
    private void sbFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sbDir = Convert.ToString(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        }


        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@sbDir);

        foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {

            string pathA = file.Name;
            int index = pathA.IndexOf(".");
            if (index > 0)
                pathA = pathA.Substring(0, index);


            string filePath = sbDir + @"\" + pathA;
            string fileName = sbDir + @"\" + file.Name;

            //Uncompress all zip files in their own directory using zip file name in the parent directory
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, filePath);

        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So do you want to create subfolder named with the same name of the zip file and decompress the content of the zip in their respective subfolders?

Comment: To answer Steve, YES, that is exactly what I am trying to do.  I want to navigate to a directory, containing dozens of zip files, select the directory and then have the program create subfolders named with the same name of the zip files and decompress the content of the zip in their respective subfolders.

Comment: Then edit your question clearly explaining what you need to achieve and wait the question to be reopened

Comment: Is my question specific enough now for it to be reopened?

Comment: Almost clear enough, but you say you have a problem and then don't explain what the problem is. Are you getting an exception, or is the program not functioning how you expect it to? Please update your question with further details.

Comment: I think your question is clear now, but it is difficult to have a question reopened. Sometimes it is better to delete the closed one and retry with a new one with the best explanation possible